# What can a Facebook app access?

Tags: facebook, accessibility

I was wondering what a Facebook Application could access, or alternatively what the API can access.
Can it retrive your current status (online/idle/offline), or the status of your friends? Can it see your friends wall-postings?

Or is the application restricted to only your information and yourself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest checking out the Facebook permissions section for further information:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/

(You will need to authenticate users to request these permissions, as described in the parent section of the above page)

Good luck :)

Comment: Thank you for a quick response. I will consult the documents you linked to. Thanks! :)